# Failed to update a row in oracle sql database from java jdbc, java code stuck at update

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm facing a problem, that for one particular record(randomly) in an Oracle SQL table, the updating and select is not working from Java JDBC code, The java control is waiting indefinitely at that update statement (application getting stuck there). I have attached **stack trace** at the bottom. This program has been executing without any issues for a few years now.

**Code:**

```
    public void updateRequestStatus(long req_id, int status){  
    int rowsAffected=0;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{   
        stmt = objCon.createStatement();
        String strUpdQry="";
        '--- some java code
        '---
        strUpdQry= "UPDATE abcrequest SET status="+status+" where request_id="+req_id;
        this.logger.printString("Before executing Update Query :: with status: "+status+", Request id: "+req_id);

        rowsAffected=stmt.executeUpdate(strUpdQry);
        this.logger.printString("After executing Update Query:: "+status+", Request id: "+req_id);  
        this.objCon.commit();           
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
            this.lg.error("SQLException at :",sqle);
            this.logger.printString("SQLException occured  "+sqle.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
            this.lg.error("Exception :",e);
            this.logger.printString("Exception occured in: "+e.getMessage());
    }       
    finally{
        closeStatement(stmt);
    }
}
```

**Things we have tried**

1. We are able to execute update query from oracle SQLDeveloper session on the same record.
2. When the application got stuck we verified related tables: `V$LOCKED_OBJECT`, `v$LOCK`, `v$session_longops`, `dba_blockers`, `v$session`, `dba_waiters` for finding any locks on table record that is making the java application to wait infinitely. But we couldn't find any.
3. If we restart the application, even for the same record update or select is freezing. If we skip that record, other records are updating without any issues.

What factors are factors causing this?

**stack trace**

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.MAREngine.unmarshalUB1(MAREngine.java:931)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.MAREngine.unmarshalSB1(MAREngine.java:893)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:369)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1891)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java:830)
    - locked <0x09c62c78> (a oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2391)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2672)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:572)
    - locked <0x04b068d8> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement)
    - locked <0x09c35338> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)
    at xxxxx.DBActions.xxxxx.getRequestAttributes(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit-1: Added new stack trace with respect to ojdbc6.**

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1000)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1814)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1779)
    - locked <0x09ec40f0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:277)
    at cas.com.database.MQDatabaseDts.updateProvRequestStatus(MQDatabaseDts.java:595)
    at cas.com.thread.NeoMQSenderThread.run(NeoMQSenderThread.java:188)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: which is the error your are getting. Also print the strUpdQry before calling the query and add the output to the question.

Comment: Is your application multithreaded? Are there other pending transactions involving that row at the same time? Did you tried changing transaction isolation?

Comment: Any software updates or patches run recently? DB updates not in sync with oracle java driver?

Comment: OT, but you should be using bind variables, not literals in your SQL statement.

Comment: @DavideCavestro Thanks for your comment.  the application is not multithreaded, and there are no pending transactions involving that row at the same time from java code, and verified the same from V$lock, V$LOCKED_OBJECT tables, and if i skip that record, other records are updating without any issue, Note: This issue is getting for some random records.

Comment: @Juan Thanks for the reply, Actually the control got stuck at executeUpdate(), There is no kind of sqlException, and the query preparation is verified and is working fine for next records. Note: These locked records are getting randomly(eg: 1 for 200) and freezing the application. and regarding updates or patches, I'm not sure but any help in finding out what causing row lock would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does v$session show?  Have you looked on the db server for any trace files that may have been created?

Comment: I seriously suspect the `UPDATE` query without the ending semicolon `;` as issue, but isn't it actually required to end a query with a `;` for `Oracle`?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer: no, not if the statement is executed through JDBC (in fact in that case, the `;` isn't allowed at all)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for that info - I'll remember that!

Comment: Could you please share the topmost part of the call stack (i.e.from a thread dump) just to see if the driver is waiting for response from the db. What do you mean with _some random records_? Do you mean that - given a record on which it got stuck now - on a subsequent execution it works fine.

Comment: How many connection you have? objCon.commit -> is auto-commit enabled? How do you manage connection pool? is it always same objCon instance?

Comment: @DavideCavestro I have attached the stack trace and found that this issue is not only for update queries but also for select queries. And this issue is happening for one particular record, to verify that we have reprocessed on the same record again code freezes, note: If I skip that record, insertion and updation is working fine on other records.  This issue is repeating for some random records in the table.

Comment: @HRgiger We are currently using only one Connection instance, which we get through DriverManager class using JDBC framework. please go through my previous comments for recent observations on this issue, thanks HRgiger

Comment: @HRgiger , I have updated to ojdbc6.jar and the issue is still replicating, I have attached new stack trace of ojdbc6.jar, we have also got one clue, In v$session there is some session_id in blocking_session column for this JDBC session_id, but we could not find any locks. please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue is because of concurrency issues in that Oracle version, that 
 is causing the java sessions getting blocked.

The issue is resolved when updated to the latest Oracle DB version in live.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `objCon.isValid()` before executing this statement because this issue looks like your connection has been disconnected under the covers. If the connection isn't valid, get a new one.

Comment: It seems like it's not a connection issue, As even if we process the same record(having issue) the code is freezing and if we skip that and process next record, update and select are working fine.

Comment: Then I suggest you upgrade your driver to a more recent one. The fact that you have "TTC7Protocol" in the exception stack trace indicates that you're using a driver that's more than 10 years old. There is a good chance that upgrading the driver will fix the issue.

Comment: As per your suggestion we have updated to ojdbc6 and issue is still replicating, we have got one clue a] in v$session there is some session_id in  blocking_session column with the JDBC session_id, we could not find any locks. b] I have updated the new stack wrt ojdbc6.  please suggest a solution.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads that can concurrently execute this updateRequestStatus method and share the same connection? If so you might need to revisit your logic to be sure that you don't have 2 threads that execute this method concurrently as you may end up in a deadlock. One quick fix would be to synchronize the method.

Comment: We are using only one thread for this entire process, Could you please explain what the stack tells. Is the JDBC waiting for sending or receiving... And what are other probable issues?

Comment: The driver is waiting for the RPC (the executeUpdate) to complete. There could be multiple reasons why the server isn't responding: network outage, sever-side crash, waiting for acquiring a row-level lock, etc. One thing you can try is to turn on auto-commit (and remove the explicit commit call).